# search an uninstall from registry key C#

Tags: c#, winforms, search, uninstallation, registrykey

I want to uninstall some app programmatically. I'm searching in this path in win registry:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

the code for searching and uninstalling is the following:

```
public string UninstallCMD;

    public bool SearchApp(string p_name)
            {
                string displayName;
                RegistryKey key;
    
    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
                foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                { 
                    RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
                    displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                
                    if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
                    {
                        UninstallCMD = subkey.GetValue("UninstallString") as string;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
    }
```

My problem is that not all the key were read. The key that I want to be read is **{56DDDFB8-7F79-4480-89D5-25E1F52AB28F}** but is ignored like the other in **{ }** (in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUlb7.png) you can see the key ignored)

The key without **{ }** were read normally (i.e. 7-zip, VLC media player, ...)

Comment: What is the bitness of your application? 32bit or 64bit? Did you deselect the `Prefer 32-bit` option in `Project->Properties->Build`?

Comment: @Jimi It's a 64bit application and I have deselected `prefer 32-bit`. The option is also grayed out and I can't click it

Comment: All right. Now, I don't know what that `p_name` is, I assume it's the `name` string you're passing to the method. -- Not sure why you have `GUID = subkey.GetValue("UninstallString") as string;`, that's not the GUID, it's the string you need to Shell out to start the uninstall procedure. Those GUIDs you're referring to are returned in the `keyName` string. Sometimes the same GUID is repeated inside `UninstallString` (since it's passed to the installer), but you'd have to extract it. Anyway, it's the same string, so no need to.

Comment: Yep. `p_name` == `name`. I've corrected the code. I pass the name of application to unistall. I want to search in registry for that application. Then I take the string to start the uninstall procedure. I've also edited some line to make code more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after recompiling solution, everything work fine.